# How to prove this claim using Mathematical Induction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

We have $n$ points on a surface and for each $3$ points, we are able to put them into a circle with radius of unit length. Prove that all of these points are on circle with radius of unit length.

My attempt for this question was something like this:
Checking the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ point with the two points that are on the border of the circle which covers the $n-1$ previous points.

Comment: Are you saying that the points are on the set $|x|=1$? This does not sound correct to me. Just look at three points very close together. (Carefully consider the difference between 'on a circle' and 'in a circle')

Comment: @Thomas I think we can put each two points on the border of a circle with radius of unit length. (considering that each 3 points can be in a circle like the one I said)
Better saying: we can move that circle until we get two points on the border of the circle. Is it true?

Comment: The border of a circle (if you are looking at the boundary of a disk) is the empty set. Are you talking about the boundary of a disk or about the disc itself?

Comment: @Thomas I don't know if I'm right! That's just what I got form the question and I'm not sure if my attempt is going to work. Do you understand anything else from this question? or any other idea?

Answer (score 3):

The claim is not true.  Let the surface be a sphere of the correct size and the four points be the corners of an inscribed regular tetrahedron.

Comment: The correct radius of the sphere is $\tfrac{3}{2\sqrt{2}}$ units. (Because I felt like it).